# How to get the important features in SOM(Self Organizing Maps)?

Tags: python, feature-selection, self-organizing-maps

I am looking at the popular python implementation of SOM : MiniSom.
A lot of blogs cite various examples like fraud detection using MiniSom.
While I do get how we can get the items associated with the outlier nodes(BMUs),
I am not able to understand how to get the important features that distinguish the outlier. What is a function or package that may help me do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you take at the python implementation of popsom (originally for R), it has a function to show feature significance: m.significance()

[popsom for python](https://github.com/njali2001/popsom)